# My app crashes with "The process aborted due to a fail fast exception"

Tags: c#, uiwebview, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, windows-8.1-universal

I am working with windows 10 universal apps, in my app i used webview control to load youtube, when i scrolling in youtube i crashes suddenly, with the out The process aborted due to a fail fast exception. this crash occurring only in mobile phone testing.

I loaded webview with youtube url like.

XAML code:

```
<WebView x:Name="webview"/>
```

CS Code: in page load

```
myWebView.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.youtube.com/"));
```

any one please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you maybe need to declare a permission in the app manifest to allow opening web content?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. What's your testing environment?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT present i am working with a sample i have that code only.

Comment: @MartinCostello i gave the permissions for access internet, apart from that have i given any other permissions.

Comment: @DeviPrasad I mean where did you test the sample?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT On Mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you described here. In my case, I had 1 link added in package.appxmanifest in content URIs. After I eliminate that link, app works fine, without crash.